# JSP, OSX 10.9.4 & ImageMagick - "/opt/local/bin/identify": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: macos, jsp, intellij-idea

I am currently working on a large legacy JSP project - not that I know anything about JSP. I have tried to set up the app in IntelliJ and I have set numerous keys in my `.MacOSX/environment.plist` file however when I try to upload an image (ImageMagick is used) in my local environment in the application I get the following error in the debug terminal (the error is all on one line):

```
.ImageUploadException: command /opt/local/bin/identify -format %w;%h; - failed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/local/bin/identify": error=2, No such file or directory
```

to make the error easier to read

```
.ImageUploadException: command /opt/local/bin/identify -format %w;%h; 
- failed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: 
Cannot run program "/opt/local/bin/identify": error=2, No such file or directory
```

After some research I create a `launchd.conf` file in the `/etc` folder and added the following line as advised on Stackoverflow and some other places:

```
setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I rebooted and I still get the same error? If I run `echo $PATH` in my terminal I get the following:

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am using a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.4 and MacPorts is installed as when I run `$ which port` I get the following: `/opt/local/bin/port`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What I did was reinstall the X-Code tools and reinstalled ImageMagick after the amends above... it all seems to work now?